# Bulk API integrate using C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I'm trying to create a Bulk API to send Data to Salesforce .Here is my Code`

```
        string userName = "XXXX";
        //Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        string password = "XXX";
        string SessionId = SalesforceLogin(userName, password);
        string JobId = CreateJob(SessionId, "insert", "Contact");
        byte[] inputFileData = null;
        string jobId = string.Empty;
        string resultId = string.Empty;
        string batchId = string.Empty;
        if (JobId.Length > 0)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo oFile = null;
            //oFile = New System.IO.FileInfo("data.csv")
            oFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"D:\request.txt");

            System.IO.FileStream oFileStream = oFile.OpenRead();
            long lBytes = oFileStream.Length;
            int a = (int)lBytes; //modified after conversion
            if ((lBytes > 0))
            {
                byte[] fileData = new byte[lBytes];
                // Read the file into a byte array
                oFileStream.Read(fileData, 0, a);   //modified after conversion
                oFileStream.Close();

                //Get the file where the Query is present
                inputFileData = fileData;
            }

             batchId= AddBatch(SessionId, JobId, inputFileData);
```

After that, I create A Job

```
private static string CreateJob(string sessionId, string sfOperation, string sfObjectName)
        {
            string str = "";
            string reqURL = "";

            byte[] bytes;

            XmlDocument reqDoc;
            XmlDocument respDoc;

            str = ""
                + "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" // added \r\n as recommended by L.B's answer
                + "<jobInfo xmlns=\"http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload\">"
                + "    <operation></operation>" // removed "+sfOperation+"
                + "    <object></object>" // removed "+sfObjectName+"
                + "    <contentType>XML</contentType>" // should be CSV, NOT XML
                + "</jobInfo>"
            ;

            reqURL = "https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/async/23.0/job";
            reqDoc = new XmlDocument();
            reqDoc.LoadXml(str);

            // added XML modifications
            reqDoc.GetElementsByTagName("operation")[0].InnerText = sfOperation;
            reqDoc.GetElementsByTagName("object")[0].InnerText = sfObjectName;

            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reqDoc.InnerXml);
            respDoc = Post(bytes, reqURL, sessionId); // create job

            string JobId = (respDoc != null) ?
                (respDoc.GetElementsByTagName("id").Count > 0) ?
                    (respDoc.GetElementsByTagName("id")[0].InnerText) :
                    "" :
                ""
            ;

            return JobId;
        }`
```

Then I create A Batch to

```
 private static string AddBatch(string sessionId, string jobId, byte[] fileBytes)
        {
            string reqURL = "https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/async/23.0/job/" + jobId + "/batch";
            XmlDocument respDoc = Post(fileBytes, reqURL, sessionId);
            string batchId = (respDoc != null) ?
                (respDoc.GetElementsByTagName("id").Count > 0) ?
                    (respDoc.GetElementsByTagName("id")[0].InnerText) :
                    "" :
                ""
            ;
            return batchId;
        }
```

Then the Post Method

```
private static XmlDocument Post(byte[] bytes, string reqURL, object sfSessionId)
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(reqURL);
            req.Method = "POST";
            if ((bytes != null))
            {
                req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            }
            req.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"; // should be text/csv; when passing a CSV file
            req.Headers.Add("X-SFDC-Session: " + sfSessionId);

            System.IO.Stream strm = req.GetRequestStream();
            if ((bytes != null))
                strm.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            strm.Close();

             HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream respStrm = resp.GetResponseStream();

            XmlDocument respDoc = new XmlDocument();
            respDoc.Load(respStrm);

            return respDoc;
        }
```

Everything Going Good But when I'm trying to save the Data on Lead it displays the Error

**InvalidBatch : Failed to parse XML. Failed to get next element**

After Creating Batch I get Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><batchInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload"><id>7512800000C8OHAAA3</id><jobId>75028000008qk53AAA</jobId><state>Queued</state><createdDate>2017-05-30T14:11:45.000Z</createdDate><systemModstamp>2017-05-30T14:11:45.000Z</systemModstamp><numberRecordsProcessed>0</numberRecordsProcessed><numberRecordsFailed>0</numberRecordsFailed><totalProcessingTime>0</totalProcessingTime><apiActiveProcessingTime>0</apiActiveProcessingTime><apexProcessingTime>0</apexProcessingTime></batchInfo>
```

One More thing After inserting the Batch, How this job will execute .I'm pasting all the code because it may help Someone if i get the Answer :).

Comment: Use following : HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();.  Then check status to see if you are getting a 200 Done.

Comment: Thanks for Ans ...I update My Question after getting the Result

Comment: Did you check the status?  Are you getting 200 DONE.  If not you need to issue multiple requests to get all the data.   Also make sure you are using http 1.0 (not 1.1).  Try following HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqURL);
            req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;  1.1 gives chunk results that doesn't work with Net L:ibrary.